# What verbs can be used in the passive voice with 'it' and an infinitive? For example: 'It was agreed to meet at twelve'

Tags: verbs, passive-voice

Practical English Usage says:

> A few verbs that are followed by infinitives (for example decide,
> agree) can also be used in passive structures beginning with it.
>
> They decided to meet at twelve. -> It was decided to meet at twelve.
>
> We agreed to open a new branch. -> It was agreed to open a new branch.
>
> However, most verbs cannot be used in this way.
>
> NOT: it is started to make a profit. or it is not expected to rain today.

'a few verbs' and 'most verbs' are ambiguous. I don't know which verbs belong to 'a few verbs'.

So when exactly can I use the passive structure: it + be + past participle + infinitive?

Comment: I doubt there’s any more pattern to share with you than that you can when you can and you can’t when you can’t. But none of it is ironclad though. For me, and despite *Practical English Usage*, there’s nothing wrong with *It is not expected to rain today*.

Comment: ***It's thought** to be a potentially long list* (at least by this thinker! :)

Comment: I'd be completely OK with saying/writing 'it is not expected to rain today'.

Comment: So would the The Tampa Bay Times: _It is not expected to rain today, and the temperature should peak in the upper 80s before dropping as low as the upper 60s overnight._

Comment: Yorkshire weather forecast: Yorkshire Post 1 Sept 2022 — It is expected to rain today

Comment: ***It's supposed** to rain more on the plain in Spain*

Answer (score 1):

**The impersonal passive**

> The impersonal passive is used with reporting verbs **such as allege,
> believe, claim, consider, estimate, expect, know, report, say, think,
> understand, etc.** It reports what an unspecified group of people say or
> believe. [bolding mine+ decide and agree]
>
> The impersonal passive has two forms:
>
> it + be + past participle + (that) + subject + verb:
>
> It is estimated that millions of people visit the site every year. It
> is believed that the walls date from the third century BCE. It is
> reported that mosquitoes transmit the disease.
>
> someone/something + be + past participle + infinitive:
>
> Millions of people are estimated to visit the site every year. The
> walls are believed to date from the third century BCE. Mosquitoes are
> reported to transmit the disease.
>
> Note that the infinitive can be simple (as above), perfect (for a past
> action) or continuous (for an action in progress).
>
> Millions are estimated to visit the site this year. (simple
> infinitive) The walls are believed to have been built in the third
> century BCE. (perfect infinitive) Mosquitoes are reported to be
> transmitting the disease. (continuous infinitive)

[advanced passive review from the British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/c1-grammar/advanced-passives-review#:%7E:text=The%20impersonal%20passive%20is%20used,of%20people%20say%20or%20believe.)